# Can you create / delete / update stored access policies if running as a Managed Identity?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-managed-identity, azurite

I'm not really sure how to test this locally, as my understanding of using Managed Identities is that my code would need to be published as an azure resource and running under that identity to access another azure resource which has given certain permissions to that identity.

In my case I want to test that my web app, when running using the managed identity, can create a stored access policy and then generate a sas against that policy. The basics of the code come from [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-stored-access-policy-define-dotnet?tabs=dotnet). However, as that article states:

> The underlying REST operation to create a stored access policy is Set
> Container ACL. You must authorize the operation to create a stored
> access policy via Shared Key by using the account access keys in a
> connection string.

So, firstly if I had my web app running in azure using a managed identity with full permissions on the storage account, would it be able to create access policies? Secondly, how can I test this locally without having to push my web app into azure? Is there a way of testing this using Azurite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through my testing it looks like a Managed Identity, even when given 'owner' permissions on the storage account cannot create / remove / update access policies. This needs to be done using StorageSharedKeyCredential, so the container client created would then have the ability to do those activities.

Answer (score 1):

You can test this locally by adding the following to your startup file in VS or VS Code, weather or not your app will be able to create access policies depends on the access you have given the managed identity but for sure if you have given it the correct access then yes it can do that.

```
  var credentials = GetDefaultAzureCredential();

 private static DefaultAzureCredential GetDefaultAzureCredential() => new(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
        {
            ExcludeManagedIdentityCredential = false,
            ExcludeInteractiveBrowserCredential = false,
            ExcludeVisualStudioCodeCredential = false,

            ExcludeEnvironmentCredential = true,
            ExcludeAzureCliCredential = true,
            ExcludeSharedTokenCacheCredential = true,
            ExcludeVisualStudioCredential = true,

            VisualStudioCodeTenantId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TenantId"),
            InteractiveBrowserTenantId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TenantId")
        });
```

Comment: How does this work then? Surely this would mean that anything that had the TenantId would be able to access the storage account?

Comment: No this is for you to use locally, it will pop a browser auth first so noone can just use it, it is not used in azure when you deploy for real when you deploy to azure your managed ident is the only thing used

Comment: Ok, so is this essentially using my identity in it's place (the one I'm logged into VS with)? So I will need to give that account access to the storage account? That doesn't feel like I'm testing the managed identity then.

Comment: the managed ident belongs to an azure resource you cannot test that locally since you do not have the resource locally but the functionality is the same so whatever you do on ident 1 you just then do on the actual managed identity and it will work

Comment: Yes, that's the conclusion I was coming to. So I suspect my only way to test it would be to actually deploy my code as part of some small app to azure, give that the managed identity and then spin up a storage account to test against.